# VLOOKUP string that is larger than options

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to search strings based on common characters from left to right in `Excel 2019`

If I search for strings shorter than lookup values in column A, this `vlookup` formula with wildcard in E2 works

```
=VLOOKUP(D2&"*",A1:B5,2,FALSE)
```

But how to search a string that is larger than the lookup values?

For `ABCDE` the output would be `H` since

**ABCDE**

**ABCDE**FG

And the output for `ABCDEFGHIJKLM` should be `Y`since `ABCDEFGHIW` is the string more similar than `ABCDEFGHIJKLM`. The equal characters to match from left to right would be at least 4, if not show "not found"

**ABCDEFGHI**JKLM

**ABCDEFGHI**W

|  | A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | **STRING** | **LETTER** |  | **STRING SMALLER THAN COL A STRINGS** | **LETTER** |
| 2 | ABCJKPOR | Q |  | ABCDE | H |
| 3 | ABCDEFG | H |  |  |  |
| 4 | ABCKKHSPLLZ | T |  | **STRING LARGER THAN COL A STRINGS** | **LETTER** |
| 5 | ABCDEFGHIW | Y |  | ABCDEFGHIJKLM | Y |

Comment: ABCDE could potentially return H or Y since it matches with first 5 characters of both ABCDEFG and ABCDEFGHIW. Is it the order of appearance, number of unmatched characters in the lookup or something else that determines what gets returned in the case of a tie like this?

Comment: When there are more than one option that share the same first characters, for example if I look for `ABCDE` and in column A there are the options `ABCDE12, ABCDE123, ABCDE1234567`, then the best match would be the one with smaller length, in this example would be `ABCDE12`. If the best options have the same length, then the answer would be the one that is first in order of appearance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are always looking at the left characters matching then:

With older versions:

```
=INDEX(VLOOKUP(LEFT(D5,LEN(D5)-ROW($ZZ$1:INDEX($ZZ:$ZZ,LEN(D5)))+1)&"*",A:B,2,FALSE),N(IF({1},SUM(--(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(LEFT(D5,LEN(D5)-ROW($ZZ$1:INDEX($ZZ:$ZZ,LEN(D5)))+1)&"*",A:B,2,FALSE))=TRUE))+1)))
```

This may require the use of Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

[image]

---

With Office 365

```
=LET(
    lkp,D5,
    lkprng,A:A,
    otprng,B:B,
    ar,XLOOKUP(
        BYROW(SEQUENCE(LEN(lkp),,0),LAMBDA(a,LEFT(lkp,LEN(lkp)-a)))&"*",
        lkprng,
        otprng,
        "",2),
    TAKE(FILTER(ar,ar<>"",""),1))
```

This iterates removing on letter from the value in D returning all matches.  Then we take the first non empty string.

[image: ![enter image description here]

---

If the match can be anywhere then we need to use the Fuzzy Lookup:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=15011

Comment: @RasecMalkic see edit.  You may need to refresh to see it.

Comment: did you get the `{}` around the formula when you used Ctrl-Shift-Enter?

Comment: It works pretty fine now. The only issue not related with your formula is that I need to search more than 3000 strings within a range like A1:B5000 and it freezes a bit for such task

Comment: Very clever to use the error count of the longer string not found to get the position of the last value before the first match. I think this calculates faster though: `=INDEX(B:B,MATCH(TRUE,NOT(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(LEFT(D5,LEN(D5)-ROW($ZZ$1:INDEX($ZZ:$ZZ,LEN(D5)))+1)&"*",A:B,2,0))),0))`

Comment: Thanks for your solution but appears #N/A in all cases. Does it work for you?

Comment: You need it entered with `Ctrl+shift+enter` (hold Ctrl+shift and when you hold them press enter, when entering the formula). You'll then see the formula surrounded in `{ }` indicating it's an array formula.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UFply.jpg (with me it doesn't show the array-brackets, since I'm on Office 365 (app version) and also unable to use key combinations using a mobile device)

Comment: Yes, entering as matrix formula (Ctrl+Shift+enter) doesn't work. Only shows #N/A with source data from `A1:B5` with strings in Col A and Letters in Col B.

Comment: Could you post a what value do you search for and what do you need returned? Are you sure you're on Excel 2019?

Comment: Yes, is Excel 2019. I'm trying to search the value in D5 that is `ABCDEFGHIJKLM`. The answer should be `Y` but appears `#N/A`

Comment: @RasecMalkic the [array formula](https://exceljet.net/glossary/array-formula)  `=INDEX($B$2:$B$5,LOOKUP(1e7,MATCH(MID(D5,1,ROW($A$4:INDEX($A:$A,LEN(D5))))&"*",$A$2:$A$5,0)))` is shorter still, and _will_ work in Excel 2019

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have an answer for vlookup, but if you ever get 365, then you can use xlookup to get H for ABCDE:

```
=XLOOKUP(D2,A2:A5,B2:B5,,1)
```